# Disable array of dates in PickMeUp jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-plugins, datepicker, calendar

How do I disable an array of dates in [PickMeUp](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp) upon initialisation?

I have an array of dates. What I want to do is disable these dates, so the user can't choose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the (quiet) party, but here's the solution.

What you need to do is load the dates into an array. You can then check this array with `PickMeUp`'s [`object render event`](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#object-render-date) and check every date against the dates from the array. If any of the dates coincide, you simply return the object `disabled: true` and the user won't be able to select the dates.

Additionally, I also return the class `disabled` to improve the disabled dates' CSS colors. This because `PickMeUp`'s default color-scheme for disabled dates is black; this makes it hard to see them.

The following **Javascript/jQuery** achieves what you want:

```
// Creating some 'sample' dates 
var datesArray = [];
var d = new Date();
for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    var tempDay = new Date(); tempDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tempDay.setDate(d.getDate()+i);
    datesArray.push(tempDay.getTime());
}

$(function () {
    $('.multiple').pickmeup({
        flat: true,
        mode: 'multiple',
        // Before rendering each date, deselect dates if in the array
        render: function(date) {
            if ($.inArray(date.getTime(), datesArray) > -1){
                return {
                    disabled   : true,
                    class_name : 'disabled'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
// Little hack to deselect current day: PickMeUp forces you to have a default date :(
$('.pmu-today').click();
```

With the following **CSS**:

```
.disabled {
    color: #5C5C8A !important;
    background: #000033;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fothun7h/)

Comment: I found the solution a few days after, had to dive into the code. But thank you for your answer, anyway! And sorry for my poor English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Nice That's good to hear. No apologies needed: I'm not a native either. For the record, you might want to accept my answer so that, in the future, people who come to this question can see the solution more easily :)

Answer (score 0):

```
pickmeup('.clndr', {
        flat      : true,
        mode      : 'range',
        calendars : 1,
        format: 'Y-m-d',
        separator: ',',
        min : new Date(),
        select_month :false,
        select_year  : false,
        render: function(date) { 
        //удаляем отсюда--
        if ((today.getMonth() + 1) < 10)  { monday_mec = '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1); } 
        var date1 = today.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + monday_mec + '-' + (today.getDate() + 3) + 'T21:00:00.000Z';
        var date2 = today.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + monday_mec + '-' + (today.getDate() + 4) + 'T21:00:00.000Z';
                //--до сюда
        //вместо date1 и date2 ставим свои даты в формате 2017-09-30T21:00:00.000Z
        var disabled_days = [new Date(date1), new Date(date2)];

        for(i = 0; i < disabled_days.length; i++) 
            if (date.toString() == disabled_days[i].toString()) { 
            return {
                    disabled   : true,
                    class_name : 'disabled_dates'
                } 
            }
         }
    }).clear();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/peretc001/us55fztz/

Comment: Please explain your answer. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.